# Max Page width for standard 1024px resolution so that no horizontal scroll bar displays?

Tags: css, html

I set the #wrapper width:1000px; however the site's still needs a horizontal scroll bar to be viewed fully for 1024 resolution .  I have 2 questions

1)How much  should i set the #wrapper width so that it doesn't need a horizontal scroll bar?

2)I want the site to be viewable for all screens(tablets, netbooks etc. apart from desktops/laptops) except smartphones or mobile devices. Would designing for 1024 resolution do the job?

Comment: Many tablets go no further than 800 pixels in width. But tell me, 1000px for the page should be OK for a 1024 screen. Unless the user has a customised desktop theme with very fat scrollbars. Can you provide a link to your site? I'll have a look.

Comment: There's only slight space on the right that's not viewable...so the horizontal scroll bar's  just minimal.   The site's on my development system so no link unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

There isnt really an accurate way to do this, depending on the users settings on there PC it wont really work, best way to do it would be using `auto` attributes

Comment: hmmm... not sure about if auto would do the job.